# Is there a PHP equivalent to sqlite3_limit?

Tags: php, sqlite

I was trying to set SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT to something higher than 500 (the current limit) I saw this - http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/limit.html to set runtime limits and later realised that it mentions "SQLITE C interface" in the heading.

Is there any PHP equivalent?

Comment: Same problem here... http://stackoverflow.com/q/16897503/89771

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the [SQLite 3](http://php.net/book.sqlite3) extension nor [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) seem to expose that function.

It's possible that PHP is using the system's sqlite3 libraries.  In that case, if you control the server, you may be able to "simply" recompile the library with a higher default value.

Comment: that would become the default max_value for all connections i make throughout the code... may not be desirable. The function (sqlite3_limit() in C) was for modification of max_value on per connection basis - which i considered much safer.

Comment: The limit itself seems harmless enough... that said, if you're hitting it, you might want to just refactor the query instead.