# Increasing Limit of Attached Databases in SQLite from PDO

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I'm working on a project that should benefit greatly from using one database file per each table, mostly because I'm trying to [avoid having the database grow too large](https://stackoverflow.com/a/811862/89771) but also because of [file locking issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1712873/89771).

I thought of using the [`ATTACH` statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) to have a "virtual" database with all my tables, but I just found out that while the upper limit of attached databases is 62 (which would be totally acceptable for me), the default limit of attached databases is in fact 10, from the [SQLite limits page](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html):

> **Maximum Number Of Attached Databases**
>
> The ATTACH statement is an SQLite extension that allows two or more
>   databases to be associated to the same database connection and to
>   operate as if they were a single database. The number of
>   simultaneously attached databases is limited to SQLITE_MAX_ATTACHED
>   which is set to 10 by default. The code generator in SQLite uses
>   bitmaps to keep track of attached databases. That means that the
>   number of attached databases cannot be increased above 62.

Since I will need to support more than 10 tables, my question is, how do I set the `SQLITE_MAX_ATTACHED` variable to a higher value from PHP (using PDO with SQLite 3)?

Comment: Looks like excellent time to start using a database.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: You and your wisdom...

Comment: @AlixAxel: did you consider switching to real database, like PostgreSQL or MySQL?

Comment: @mvp: I didn't, because the whole point of what I am trying to do revolves around SQLite, I could get into specifics but I would rather not. Without wanting to come off as harsh, this is a question where I need a objective answer (that is either a solution - perhaps using a PRAGMA or some undocumented PHP/PDO function, or not) for what I am asking and not for what you think I *might* need. And SQLite is a real (though serverless) database.

Comment: @AlixAxel: I understand where are you coming from. Don't get me wrong - I absolutely *love* SQLite for what it can do when used properly, and I agree that it is real database. That being said, sometimes you should just step back and re-evaluate what you are doing - think out of the box if you will. If you are *really* suffering from SQLite locking issues, then PostgreSQL solves this perfectly.

Comment: Update: The maximum number of attached databases cannot be increased above 125.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These limits are [compile-time options](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html).

You must recompile PHP to change them.

Comment: Not quite accurate, from the page you linked to: "The compile-time options normally set a hard upper bound that can be changed at run-time on individual database connections using the sqlite3_limit() interface".

Comment: "*Hard* upper bound" means that it can only be *lowered* at run-time.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. The other page I linked to states that explicitly, guess it skipped my eye... Do you know if that option will be listed in `PRAGMA compile_options;` after I recompile SQLite?

Comment: These limits, despite being set at compile time, are not considered compile options.

Comment: What is the syntax to change SQLITE_LIMIT_ATTACHED using php?

Comment: @Elyor To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: @CL. I posted the question. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365189/attach-unlimited-sqlite-databases-using-php